# SAP ERP integration with C++

Tags: c++, .net, sap-erp, saprfc, sap-r3

Is there a SDK for C++ or .NET available for SAP ERP 4.0 as I need to read and write data into it?

Comment: Could you be more precise about what software and version you really mean? SAP R/3 Release 4.0 was published more than ten years ago, so I doubt you really mean this...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what version SAP ERP 4.0 refers to, but there is certainly the RFC SDK that you can use (can be made to work with C++ and .Net):

Very old version:
http://help.sap.com/saphelp_40b/helpdata/pt/8c/20e2bf493311d1894a0000e829fbbd/frameset.htm

Recent version:
http://help.sap.com/erp2005_ehp_04/helpdata/EN/22/04287a488911d189490000e829fbbd/frameset.htm

Answer (score 0):

Building on the previous answer: with the C++ RFC SDK you can call ABAP functions and objects on the SAP side. So the actual reading or writing of the SAP data will be done by ABAP code on the other side.

Looking at this from the very high level you have two options with RFC:

- find a factory SAP function that does what you want. i.e. write or read the SAP data
- or write your own custom ABAP script that does exactly you wanted

In both cases you need to nail down what parameters you need to pass and receive to the ABAP you call, and make sure your RFC calls does that.