# Interfacing C++ with SAP ERP

Tags: c++, sap-erp, saprfc

Is it possible in C++ Visual studio that I can connect to SAP Database, write data to it ?

For example, I'm doing a facial recognition project and it's already done, but the remaining part is to connect SAP and write the Face ID of the user to the HR database plus the time stamp.

Comment: so far I have not encountered a "Is it possible..?" programming question for which the answer was "no"

Comment: @idclev463035818 Is it possible to solve the halting problem in Visual Studio? You have now.

Comment: I don't know the answer to the question, but I'm guessing it would involve money, perhaps even some highly paid consultants (HPCs).

Comment: @john Every question involves money :)

Comment: @AhmedSaleh I actually checked the SAP web site. They have an open source DB called OrientDB, and they even recommend that you ask questions about it here! Are you using OrientDB?

Comment: @john No I'm not using it. I will search if it supports C++

Comment: @john So simply I connect to that database, change whatever I need, and would sap read it ?

Comment: @john OrientDB doesn't work with C++

Comment: @john It doesn't also work on windows :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SAP ERP 4.0 Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656361/sap-erp-4-0-integration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahmed, first you need to determine what the database your SAP system is running on, doesn't sound like you know so get that information first so you can get the right driver. Then the answer to your question is, yes. Create a connection using your driver first to connect to the server and database you are trying to update, you'll need to get the server name, database name and database credentials for your DBA, then in Visual Studio go to View > Server Explorer to add access to your new connection and then write your SQL to update insert you records.

The second part, yes if you write to the database tables properly it will show up in SAP.